# Cluster Robust Standard Errors vs GMM

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, generalized-moments, clustered-standard-errors

I want to estimate a linear model on a panel data set using fixed effects and my dependent variable has positive serial correlation. I also have to address heteroskedasticity. I have read that two-way clustered standard errors is the best way to address this problem but I could also use the Arellano and Bond GMM estimator. My data set is a very large unbalanced panel that is longer than it is wide but nothing that should restrict asymptotics in either direction. Which method is better or what do I need to consider when choosing between these two methods?